# How to get price*quantity conditionally using CASE

Tags: mysql, node.js

If I have sale_price, I do sale_price * quantity to represent the total price,
If you don't have a sale_price, you want price_origin * quantity to represent the total price.

I tried using CASE as below, but I get this error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') )AS products FROM users u JOIN cart_order c_o ON c_o.user_id = u' at line 11

what am i doing wrong? Is there another way? I need help.

```
const readUserCart = async userId => {
  const userCart = await myDataSource.query(
    `SELECT u.id AS userId, u.name AS userName,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'productName', p.name, 
          'quantity', c_o.quantity,
          'priceOrigin', REPLACE(p.price_origin, '.', ','),
          'salePrice', REPLACE(p.sale_price, '.', ','),
          'productThumbnail', t_i.default_img,
          'status', c_o.status,
          'price', CASE 
                  WHEN p.sale_price = null 
                  THEN REPLACE(p.price_origin * quantity, '.', ',') 
                  ELSE REPLACE(p.sale_price * quantity, '.', ',')
        )
      )AS products
    FROM users u
    JOIN cart_order c_o ON c_o.user_id = u.id
    JOIN products p ON p.id = c_o.product_id
    WHERE u.id = ?
    GROUP BY u.id`,
    [userId]
  );
  return userCart;
};
```

Comment: You're missing an `end` after the `else` branch of the `case`. In addition, `null`s are checked with the `is` operator, not the `=` operator.

Comment: Please check if your tags are correct to get proper answers. I believe you are using node.js so if that is the case, remove your "javascript" tag and replace it with "node.js".

Comment: I changed to node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'sale_price is null' against 'sale_price = null'. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: 'price', CASE WHEN p.sale_price is null THEN REPLACE(p.price_origin * quantity, '.', ',') ELSE REPLACE(p.sale_price * quantity, '.', ',')

I tried this, but I get the same error.

Comment: I think additionally you should put 'END'  in your CASE statement . But I am afraid that you have more syntax error. Maybe you should debug this querry. Split them on smaller parts and test them independently.